# Rust color spots on Tomato Leaves, and Caterpillars

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, tomatoes, pest-control, container-gardening

I am getting these spots on tomatoes in my green house.  I am in North Carolina so it is really hot.  Caterpillars also have been eating the leaves.  They mostly like the kale leaves though.  How can I keep them from eating the leaves and what is causing the spots and what can I do to treat it. [image]

Comment: Good question; if could include an overall illustration, closer illustration of the spots, a close illustration of a caterpillar, overall height, the strains of tomatoes, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, size of container, soil, drainage, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, and hours of direct sunlight per day, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!